# Why does Curl ignore the given range?

Tags: curl, youtube

I need to download a specific part of a Youtube video using Curl. (Let's say I want to download the first 2MB) I'm using the **-r** switch in Curl to achieve this. It works for non-youtube links, but the range I specify with -r is ignored for Youtube links. Curl downloads the entire video file, instead of downloading the chunk I want. How can I do this?
Thanks in advance!

(A sample code I used:)

> curl --cookie **"VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE=EIBGUtRnRx4;
>   demographics=d9e6a6b806922b989c443b57cc40cf59e3QDAAAAYWdlaRQAAAB0BgAAAGdlbmRlcnQBAAAAbTA=;
>   s_tempdata-336183159=ei=xBC_UeOJLs6hkgXB7oGwDw&ved=CDcQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-3430648675=ei=xBC_UeOJLs6hkgXB7oGwDw&ved=CEwQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-877158463=ei=xBC_UeOJLs6hkgXB7oGwDw&ved=CF8Qvxs;
>   s_tempdata-2333910030=ei=xBC_UeOJLs6hkgXB7oGwDw&ved=CHsQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-3498387738=ei=xBC_UeOJLs6hkgXB7oGwDw&ved=CDIQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-106278690=ved=CFcQvxs&ei=Q9LCUfqrJMK0kgX3ioGgBw;
>   s_tempdata-1014563062=ved=CFoQvxs&ei=cxDEUf3OAsiekQXjiYCACA;
>   d9ji4.resume=uFMMXRoSxnA:183;
>   s_tempdata-1950472349=ei=ywzMUcPiJqekmQXrtIC4Cw&ved=CCMQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-350957551=ei=UxDMUaWGJOTnmAWnmIHICg&ved=CDMQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-3561588006=ei=MD_MUZyPGeTnmAX3koHgBw&ved=CDIQvxs;
>   s_tempdata-1460032003=ei=1VDOUbSyIYjOmgXtyYGAAQ&ved=CA0Qvxs;
>   s_tempdata-2286494229=ei=lFXOUfiMLerbmAXrgoG4Aw&ved=CIABEL8b;
>   s_tempdata-1936772083=ei=lFXOUfiMLerbmAXrgoG4Aw&ved=CH0Qvxs;
>   s_tempdata-190970993=feature=g-high-crv&ei=S9zOUZzYLsi3ygHS9YD4BA&ved=CIgBEPklKAE;
>   __utma=27069237.288981257.1372343761.1372343761.1372511855.2; __utmb=27069237.5.10.1372511855; __utmz=27069237.1372343761.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmc=27069237; YSC=TwN0bcR_vzM; recently_watched_video_id_list=cc05ffe7b8a53d9d2dbcb9695b1b5354WwEAAABzCwAAAEhTZUltcWJWMzBz; ACTIVITY=1372523413722; PREF=f1=50000000&fv=11.2.202&al=en;"** -o
>   ~/Downloads/File.part -r 0-2000000
>   "http://r4---sn-nau-jhcl.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?id=1d27889aa6d5df4b&ipbits=8&factor=1.25&ms=au&mt=1372523374&fexp=925614%2C906370%2C912519%2C904825%2C900222%2C909546%2C906397%2C928201%2C929123%2C929915%2C929906%2C929907%2C929125%2C929127%2C925714%2C929917%2C929919%2C931202%2C912512%2C912515%2C912521%2C906838%2C906840%2C931913%2C904830%2C919373%2C933701%2C904122%2C900816%2C909421%2C912711%2C907228&mv=m&burst=40&algorithm=throttle-factor&expire=1372545822&sver=3&source=youtube&newshard=yes&cp=U0hWR1VPU19HTENONl9NSVdJOkNGQUpTdVJvVnY0&upn=a9WEy2DAZiY&ip=103.21.166.17&key=yt1&itag=34&sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&signature=399599C4C262CCEAED9AB8AEA48A71DDFADFB7CF.08C556136636AFD52BE0318D3E4AECAC1ABFB7C5"

Comment: Please Naveen to talk us about the solution you used to bypass this limitation. Downloading the whole video in server is bad for performance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry there is no way to bypass. Even if curl requests a specific range of bytes, some weak servers sends the whole file. Such servers do not offer download pause/resume support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the YouTube servers don't support the range parameter or they ignore it. From the [cURL docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Why_does_my_HTTP_range_requests):

> **4.11 Why does my HTTP range requests return the full document?**
>
> Because the range may not be supported by the server, or the server
>   may choose to ignore it and return the full document anyway.